# Elixir Function Evaluation

Tags: elixir

New to the Elixir language, I definitely appreciate the concise syntax and powerful runtime environment.

The simple question below is under what circumstances will the get_horizontal_line() function be re-evaluated?

The broader question I have as I learn this language is about the execution environment and compiler optimizations. I am slowly working my way through the Elixir documentation, and next I plan to read the Erlang docs, then I am looking for information about the runtime environment (VM).

Does anyone have recommendations about where to go to learn more about the VM system architecture and compiler? Before I look at the Erlang VM source code.

```
def get_horizontal_line, do: String.duplicate("-", 80)
def get_horizontal_line(n), do: String.duplicate("-", n)

# Binds the result of calling the function but does not execute it to determine the result.
x = get_horizontal_line()
y = get_horizontal_line()

# Forces evaluation of the function.
IO.puts(x)

# Does this force re-evaluation?
IO.puts(y)

# Binds the result of calling the function but does not execute it to determine the result.
x = get_horizontal_line(80)
y = get_horizontal_line(80)

# Forces evaluation of the function.
IO.puts(x)

# Does this force re-evaluation?
IO.puts(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

def get_horizontal_line, do: String.duplicate("-", 80)
def get_horizontal_line(n), do: String.duplicate("-", n)

This defines two functions with one clause. The first function takes no parameters, and the second function takes one.

```
# Binds the result of calling the function but does not execute it to determine the result.
x = get_horizontal_line()
y = get_horizontal_line()
```

Both these expression evaluate the function call to `get_horizontal_line`. So I'm unsure what you mean with "does not execute it". There is no lazy evaluation in Elixir.
At this point the `get_horizontal_line` function has been called and executed twice.

```
# Forces evaluation of the function.
IO.puts(x)
```

The variable `x` has been bound to the result of `get_horizontal_line()` above, so this just prints its value.

```
# Does this force re-evaluation?
IO.puts(y)
```

The variable `y` has been bound to the result of `get_horizontal_line()` above, so this just prints its value.

```
# Binds the result of calling the function but does not execute it to determine the result.
x = get_horizontal_line(80)
y = get_horizontal_line(80)

# Forces evaluation of the function.
IO.puts(x)

# Does this force re-evaluation?
IO.puts(y)
```

And this is just the same behaviour as above.

I don't know if this answers your question.

With respect to learning more about the Erlang VM, the BEAM book comes highly recommended and is free[1].

[1] https://github.com/happi/theBeamBook

Comment: Hi Christophe thank you very much for your response. I was under the impression that Elixir supports lazy evaluation and will not evaluate a function until the output is required.

I don't understand the conditions under which evaluation is forced.

Are you saying elixir does not support lazy evaluation in this way?

Comment: Elixir uses eager evaluation.

Comment: Ah I see. Well Elixir does use lazy evaluation in certain contexts does it not?

Comment: I don't think it does, no.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if we use a different example we can see how this is working more clearly.  Consider the following:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def bar, do: DateTime.utc_now()
end

x = Foo.bar()
y = Foo.bar()

Process.sleep(1_000)

IO.puts("#{x} executed 1 second before #{DateTime.utc_now()}")
IO.puts("#{y} executed mere microseconds after #{x}")
```

which produces output something like this:

```
2021-09-10 15:50:54.996566Z executed 1 second before 2021-09-10 15:50:56.000597Z
2021-09-10 15:50:54.998613Z executed mere microseconds after 2021-09-10 15:50:54.996566Z
```

You will notice that calls to `Foo.bar/0` are executed at run-time where they appear (i.e. when their output is assigned to a variable).  You can see that `x` and `y` are not *identical*, but you can see that `Foo.bar/0` executes as quickly as possible.

It may be worth mentioning one caveat to this: when a function is called somewhere floating inside a module (and not from within another function do/end block), it gets executed at *compile time* (not at run-time).  Most frequently I see this when binding a module attribute:

```
defmodule Foo do
  @x some_function()
end
```

This is so much of a gotcha when reading application config (as one example), that Elixir now warns when you try to use `Application.get_env/3` in places where would get evaluated at compile time.

This answer only seeks to clarify the first part of your question re code evaluation.  It might be best to leave questions about compiler optimizations and the Erlang VM to their own dedicated questions.

Comment: Thanks Everett. Interesting about the attribute binding. When I am writing code I tend to think ahead to the optimizations and try to write clean, efficient code. This is non-standard practice and goes against the crawl-walk-run convention which is to make it work, then make it work well, then make it pretty. It's a pretty basic thing to understand that the function is re-executed each call in a conventional OO language but here I was under the impression that ...

Comment: ...a) lazy evaluation dictates the function will be evaluated only when required (ambiguous but certainly when needed for I/O), and b) the bound value returned by the function is immutable and will never be regenerated.

Comment: What I’m really trying to accomplish is a) A global constant consisting of 80 ‘-’ characters; and b) Caching inside get_horizontal_line(n) inside a hashmap for each n. Because the function may be called 1M times with n=60, 900k times n=61, etc. but never for n=81. This is not all that necessary for this particular use case but is representative of problems often encountered when designing computational algorithms.